# How can I transfer pictures into iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm testing out a few things and want to do some screen grabs to show the difference depending on different pics but I can't easily get them on the device. I'm using React Native and I'm on a mac using Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply drag the image into the simulator and it'll work.